# Error 1004 Macro Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently having some issues with VBA and the error 1004. I checked on the Internet but, unfortunately, couldn't find the solution.

I'm working on data transfer between Excel and an other base. I'm currently on the first part of the work : the shape of the new document before the transfer. In fact, I can have text with more than 250 characters on my first database while the other one wants me to split all of the documents each 250 characters (as you can check on the program) and add a number associated to help to gather the information.

It works very well until I reach the line `Sheets("LibImport").Range("F" & ligneLib) = Mid(Sheets("NCXL").Range("B" & ligneNC), 250 * (j - 1) + 1, 250)` with *j = 2*, *LigneLib = 3899* and a text with 257 characters. This code already worked for texts with more than 500 characters that is why I don't understand the issue.

Moreover, When I delete all of the lines to start the macro again, I still have the error on the same line on the first loop. However, it works again only when I restart Excel.

Please find below the details of the macro :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Libelle()

    Dim ligneLib As Integer
    Dim ligneNC As Integer
    Dim endLoop As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    ligneNC = 3
    ligneLib = 1

    For i = 1 To 3003

        endLoop = Round_Up(Len(Sheets("NCXL").Range("B" & ligneNC)) / 250)

        For j = 1 To endLoop 'Texte description

            Sheets("LibImport").Range("A" & ligneLib) = "100"
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("B" & ligneLib) = Sheets("NCXL").Range("A" & ligneNC) & "-DESC"
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("C" & ligneLib) = "NONCONFO"
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("D" & ligneLib) = j
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("F" & ligneLib) = Mid(Sheets("NCXL").Range("B" & ligneNC), 250 * (j - 1) + 1, 250)

            ligneLib = ligneLib + 1

        Next

        endLoop = Round_Up(Len(Sheets("NCXL").Range("C" & ligneNC)) / 250)

        For j = 1 To endLoop 'Texte cause

            Sheets("LibImport").Range("A" & ligneLib) = "100"
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("B" & ligneLib) = Sheets("NCXL").Range("A" & ligneNC) & "-CAUSE"
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("C" & ligneLib) = "NONCONFO"
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("D" & ligneLib) = j
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("F" & ligneLib) = Mid(Sheets("NCXL").Range("C" & ligneNC), 250 * (j - 1) + 1, 250)

            ligneLib = ligneLib + 1

        Next

        endLoop = Round_Up(Len(Sheets("NCXL").Range("E" & ligneNC)) / 250)

        For j = 1 To endLoop 'Texte action corrective

            Sheets("LibImport").Range("A" & ligneLib) = "100"
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("B" & ligneLib) = Sheets("NCXL").Range("A" & ligneNC) & "-DSCCOR"
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("C" & ligneLib) = "NONCONFO"
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("D" & ligneLib) = j
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("F" & ligneLib) = Mid(Sheets("NCXL").Range("E" & ligneNC), 250 * (j - 1) + 1, 250)

            ligneLib = ligneLib + 1

        Next

        endLoop = Round_Up(Len(Sheets("NCXL").Range("D" & ligneNC)) / 250)

        For j = 1 To endLoop 'Texte action curative

            Sheets("LibImport").Range("A" & ligneLib) = "100"
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("B" & ligneLib) = Sheets("NCXL").Range("A" & ligneNC) & "-DECIS"
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("C" & ligneLib) = "NONCONFO"
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("D" & ligneLib) = j
            Sheets("LibImport").Range("F" & ligneLib) = Mid(Sheets("NCXL").Range("D" & ligneNC), 250 * (j - 1) + 1, 250)

            ligneLib = ligneLib + 1

        Next

        ligneNC = ligneNC + 1

    Next

End Sub

Function Round_Up(ByVal val As Double) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer
    result = Round(val)
    If result >= val Then
        Round_Up = result
    Else
        Round_Up = result + 1
    End If
End Function
```

Thanks,
Cédric.

Comment: Can you provide `Sheets("NCXL").Range("B" & ligneNC).value`?

Comment: The value is : "1- Ø15 (0/+0,06) hors tolérance maxi jusqu'à 15,12 (TLNEP pointe sur environ 2mm).=> 4pces
2- Deux Ø dans le Ø de 15 ( Ø 15,04 / 16,04) => Casse outil => tri de 2 paniers => 16pces
3- Pièce courte n=1
4- Copeau de coupe non évacué (Reste "accroché") => 1pce". I tried to add an invisible character before the "=" and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 251st character of your example text is an `=` symbol. When you write that to a cell, Excel assumes you're entering a formula.

To work around this issue, precede the text with a `'` as you would if you were keying it manually:

```
Sheets("LibImport").Range("F" & ligneLib) = "'" & Mid(Sheets("NCXL").Range("B" & ligneNC), 250 * (j - 1) + 1, 250)
```

They won't be visible in Excel, but you ***might*** need to account for them if you're doing other things later with the contents of that cell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the solution ! It works well for all of the sheet now